# How to create animate header without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've used JavaScript just for this purpose but it only works when I refresh the browser ...

```
<script> 
var scroll = window.scrollY ; 
var header = document.getElementById("header");

function my(){

    if (scroll >= header.scrollHeight) {
        header.style.height = 100 +"px";
    } else {header.style.height = 250 + "px";}
}

my();
</script>
```

Comment: The scroll only works after you refresh or it doesn't work at all ?

Comment: no , does it work when i refreshing this

Comment: does it show any error on the console or no ?

Comment: There is no Error , the problem is which for each work this code, I have to refresh the browser

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add a scroll event listener :

```
var scroll, header = document.getElementById("header");

function my() {

    scroll = window.scrollY;

    if (scroll >= header.clientHeight) header.style.height = 100 + "px";
    else header.style.height = 250 + "px";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', my, false);
window.addEventListener('load', my, false);
```

Also added a listener that will respond to when the page has fully loaded, this will make sure the function executes when the user lands on the page and a scroll position was cached before...